# Routes for accessing controllers inside vendor folder of laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have `LfmController.php` of tswaler laravel-filemanager package with folder structure such as `project\vendor\tsawler\laravel-filemanager\src\controllers\LfmController.php`.

I used route as `Route::get('/laravel-filemanager', 'Tsawler\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\LfmController@show');` for accessing that controller's `show()` method.But it gives:

`ReflectionException in Container.php line 737:
Class App\Http\Controllers\Tsawler\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\LfmController does not exist` error.This worked in my previous project but it now doesn't work on current project.What should be route structure to access controller inside vendor folder,like above?How to debug this kind of issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add '\' in the beginning of the controller namespace:

```
Route::get('/laravel-filemanager', '\Tsawler\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\LfmController@show');
```

By default, routes.php assumes your controller is in 'App\Http\Controllers' namespace but adding '\' will cause it to look in the root namespace.

Comment: ,so adding '\' will take the location from root of vendor folder is it?

Comment: It will then look into the entire root namespace of the application, including the files in vendor folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to set 'use_package_routes' to false in the config/lfm.php to enable my custom routes.